# Navigate pagination with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to navigate a list of links that looks like this:
[image: this list of links]

from a series of webpages like  [this one](https://dati.comune.milano.it/callgroup/e6528afc-bd2c-417b-99a8-d7704f942a42) and then retrieve the links on each one.
This is the HTML:

```html
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="/dataset groups=heal&amp;_groups_limit=0&amp;page=1">1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/dataset?groups=heal&amp;_groups_limit=0&amp;page=2">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/dataset?groups=heal&amp;_groups_limit=0&amp;page=3">3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="disabled">
    <a href="#">...</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/dataset?groups=heal&amp;_groups_limit=0&amp;page=7">7</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/dataset?groups=heal&amp;_groups_limit=0&amp;page=2">»</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I managed to find the number of pages, so I am trying to iterate over that.
My idea was to select the active element, and the click() on the next one. Being unfamiliar with Xpath I am stumbling on how to do that.

This is the code I am using:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[class='active']/a//following").click()`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The link for the page you're scrapping doesn't work.

Comment: Oops, fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the urls are in the format BASE_URL+page=NUM_PAGE, you could simply get the maximum page number (7 in your case).

In that way you can build all the urls with something like:

```
BASE_URL = "https://dati.comune.milano.it/dataset?groups=heal"
urls = []
for page_num in range(1, MAX_PAGES):
    urls.append(f"{BASE_URL}&page={page_num}")
```

In this way you'll have all the pages without having to click anything, just knowing the maximum number of pages which you can easily find as you already did.

**SELENIUM SOLUTION**

There are probably one thousand ways and more to do this in a cleaner way, but this one works for me. Simply loop over the list of numbers until finding the "active" as you said and click the following.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

BASE_URL = "https://dati.comune.milano.it/dataset?groups=heal&page=1" #first page

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()
    )
driver.get(BASE_URL)

url_list_xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/section[1]/div[2]/ul" # this is the page bar at the bottom

to_click = False
last_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/section[1]/div[2]/ul/li[5]/a") \
    .get_attribute("href") # find last page
current_page = BASE_URL

# iterate over the urls and click the next url after the active one
while current_page!=last_page:
    ul = driver.find_element_by_xpath(url_list_xpath)
    for li in ul.find_elements_by_tag_name("li"):
        if to_click:
            break
        if li.get_attribute("class") == 'active':
            to_click = True
    to_click = False  
    current_page = li.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")[0].get_attribute("href")
    driver.get(current_page)
```

Comment: Yeah - that's what I did in the mean time. But I was looking for a solution using Selenium for replicability.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it only works with the 'groups=heal' -- other dataset groups have different pagination attributes. I could retrieve them but it seemed not very elegant.

Comment: I added the Selenium version, it should work :) for other datasets you can simply get the pagination attribute parsing the url, since I see that each attribute follows the "groups=", so you could use a regex or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED ( I adapted the code to your link)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://dati.comune.milano.it/callgroup/e6528afc-bd2c-417b-99a8-d7704f942a42')
hrefs = [] #will contain the final list of links
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") #scrolls to the bottom of the page
# get tags
hrefs_in_view = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') #grabs all elements tagged 'a' (that contain links)
# finding relevant hrefs
for elem in hrefs_in_view:
    if isinstance(elem,str) or elem is None:     #remove some irrelevants elements
        continue
    if 'dataset' in elem.get_attribute('href'): #all links should contain the word 'dataset'. You can change this and adapt it to your needs #if the link corresponds to your needs
        hrefs.append(elem.get_attribute('href')) #add it to the list
```

The list hrefs will contain all the links you need.